# Background getting restricted to a certain height

Tags: css

I am trying to implement the CSS Code as given below, but the background height is getting limited to a certain point from the top and not covering the entire div. Once I remove the float:right or float:left, then it is again showing properly.

What might be the problem?

```
   #container3 {
    background: #FE7400;
}


#third #area1 {
        float:left;
        width:550px;
    }

    #contactform {
        width:300px;
        float:right;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your div's CSS-

```
overflow: auto;
```

If it still doesn't work, try-

```
min-height: 250px;
```

or any other size you wanna give. May be that'll help!!

Answer (score 0):

I estimate your HTML code is as below.
container3

```
<div id="container3">
    <div id="third">
    <!-- YOUR CONTENT-->
        <div id="area1">
        <!-- YOUR CONTENT-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contactform">
    <!-- YOUR CONTENT-->
    </div>
</div>
```

try adding this line to the CSS:

```
.clear{clear:both;}
```

then chage html code to:

```
<div id="container3">
    <div id="third">
    <!-- YOUR CONTENT-->
        <div id="area1">
        <!-- YOUR CONTENT-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contactform">
    <!-- YOUR CONTENT-->
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this can fix you problem.